# Datatable Ajax Request to get in Codeigniter Controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to send last value (**af**) of this URL `www.example.com/country/AF.html` through AJAX data and want to read this data in Codeigniter Controller but unable to retrieve data. Please help

Datatable Ajax Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var UserURL = window.location.href.split("/").pop();
    var newurl = UserURL.split("/").slice(-1).join().split(".").shift();
    $('#countryiptable').DataTable({
        "pageLength": 50,
        "info": false,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        'ajax': {
            'url': "country/getlist",
            "type": "POST",
            "data":{"country_code": newurl},
            "dataType": "json",
            "dataSrc": function (jsonData){
                return jsonData.data;
            }
        }
    });
} );
```

and here is my Codeigniter Controller;

```
    public function getlist(){

        echo $this->input->post('country_code');
        $countryiso2    = strtoupper($this->input->post('country_code'));       
        //echo "hi";
        $list = $this->CountryModel->getCountry($countryiso2);

        $data = array();
        $no = $_POST['start'];
        foreach ($list as $iplist) {
        // print_r($data);die;
        $no++;
        $row = array();
        $row[] = $no;
        $row[] = $iplist->startip;
        $row[] = $iplist->registry_name;
        $row[] = $iplist->totalip;
        $row[] = $iplist->country_code;
        $row[] = $iplist->ip_type;

        $data[] = $row;

        //$_POST['draw']='';
        }

        $output = array(
            "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
            "recordsTotal" => $this->CountryModel->count_all(),
            "recordsFiltered" => $this->CountryModel->count_filtered(),
            "data" => $data,
        );
        //output to json format
       echo json_encode($output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try just sending the data as newurl, not a json array country_code: newurl.  Then, just use this->input->post() and see if that gives you the string `af`

Comment: I am unable to get "data":{"country_code": newurl}, into Codeigniter. I am not sure , how to check even this data is going to Controller or not.

Comment: When is your datatable sending ajax?  Isn't that for pagination purposes? Each time the user clicks next page, ajax is called to get contents for the next page of data to show?

Comment: what are `"pageLength": 50,
        "info": false,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,` these values ??